# Perl smtp email send is not working

Tags: perl, email, smtp, timeout

I'm trying to send emails from my gmail account, and get the error:

```
Error sending email: Connect failed :IO::Socket::INET: connect: timeout at /home/tas/perl5/lib/perl5/Email/Send/SMTP/TLS.pm line 45
```

I've tried several different email adresses (gmail and others) but the result is the same.

I use this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perlml
use Email::Send;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my $mailer = Email::Send->new( {
    mailer => 'SMTP::TLS',
    mailer_args => [
        Host => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        Port => 587,
        User => 'XXXX@gmail.com',
        Password => 'XXXXXXXXX',
        Hello => 'fayland.org',
    ]
} );

use Email::Simple::Creator; # or other Email::
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        From    => 'XXXX@gmail.com',
        To      => 'XXXX@gmail.com',
        Subject => 'test',
    ],
    body => 'test',
);
eval { $mailer->send($email) };
die "Error sending email: $@" if $@;
```

What is wrong here? Any other ways to send emails using smtp?

Comment: You do not appear to be reading the error message carefully. A  `connect: timeout` should have nothing to do with what address you're sending to.  Your connection to the SMTP server is timing out, which implies that there's a firewall on your Internet connection that is dropping your outbound traffic... nothing to do with your code or the modules you're using.  Troubleshoot that problem. Try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` or `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587`. What do you see?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, and how can i run it on server? I have only ftp and cpanel acsess to my website...

Comment: You can also use [`Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail). I have tested it [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1170831). If you don't want to change your gmail account settings to allow access for less secure apps, you could try to use OAuth2 authentications, but I was not able to find out how to do this in Perl. I managed to do it in Python though, using [python-oauth2](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2) .

Comment: @adrenalin in that case, you are not in an environment where you can troubleshoot this further, and will need to contact the vendor or your next level of support, as mentioned by Dave Cross, below.  In a restricted environment, such access may not be allowed by the vendor.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have the same problem with Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error sending email: Connect failed :IO::Socket::INET: connect: timeout at /home/tas/perl5/lib/perl5/Email/Send/SMTP/TLS.pm line 45

Looks like there is nothing wrong with your Perl code. It looks like this is a networking problem. Something in your network is preventing you from connecting to Gmail on port 587.

You probably need to discuss this with the system support people for your server.